# SubConsulta MySql 1

Tags: mysql

Motta,

Obrigado pela agilidade, mas esta instrução esta aparecendo somente o maior salario. Tentei o INNER JOINT,  e quase consegui. Imagine que eu queira compara o salario de pessoas com o mesmo cargo. Veja se consegue entender com a imagem anexa.

[image: Exemplo]

Amigos,

Gostaria da Ajuda de vocês em MySql, tenho uma tabela de funcionários que tem apenas três colunas, NOME, CARGO e SALARIO, quero montar um consulta que me traga toda esta tabela e nela contenha o maior valor de salario para o cargo. Totalizando 4 Colunas (NOME, CARGO, SALARIO E MAIOR_SALARIO_P_CARGO. Isto é para verificar a variação.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site! Por favor edite sua pergunta original com as informações adicionais, em vez de criar uma nova pergunta ou tentar editar uma das respostas. Esta possivelmente será fechada como duplicata, mas não se preocupe que isso é só uma questão de organização do site. Com o tempo você pega o jeito :)

Comment: Você também pode remover esta "pergunta", já que ela de fato não é uma pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Acredito que essa query pode resolver, não cheguei a testá-la.

```
SELECT
    T1.NOME,
    T1.CARGO,
    T1.SALARIO_ATUAL,
    (
        SELECT MAX(SALARIO_ATUAL)
        FROM TABELA T2
        WHERE T2.CARGO = T1.CARGO
    ) AS MAIOR_SALARIO_PARA_CARGO
FROM TABELA T1
```

Comment: Alan, funcionou perfeitamento...